# How to SELECT TOP 10 per group with ranking

Tags: sql-server, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, row-number, dense-rank

I want to select the TOP 3 most viewed `Products` by `Country` and `ProductType` in each `PriceGrouping` over the past 7 days.

For example, I want:

- Top 3 Blue Widgets in Japan UNDER 500 dollars
- Top 3 Blue Widgets in Japan OVER 500 dollars
- Top 3 Red Widgets in Japan UNDER 500 dollars
- Top 3 Red Widgets in Japan OVER 500 dollars
- Top 3 Blue Widgets in Russia under 500 dollars
- etc

I rank each rounded `LatLng` in order to group `Products` by location, which creates a geoJSON for a Google Map data layer. Each rounded `LatLng` has a marker with an infowindow showing one or more `Products` in that location.

I want to show how each `Product` compares to others of the same `ProductType` in each `Country`.

For example, Marker1 shows:

```
Product      Type      Views       Comparison
-----------------------------------------------------------------
ABC          Type1     650         No.1 of Blue Widgets in Russia
DEF          Type2     341         No.6 of Red Widgets in Russia
```

Marker2 shows:

```
Product      Type      Views       Comparison
-----------------------------------------------------------------
XYZ          Type1     543         No.2 of Blue Widgets in Russia
RST          Type2     943         No.1 of Red Widgets in Russia
```

`PRODUCTS` table:

```
ProductID int
ProductType varchar(30)
Price DECIMAL (10,0)
```

`VIEWS` table:

Every time a product is viewed on the website, a record is created in the Views table.

```
ProductID int
ViewDate datetime
```

SQL:

```
WITH Weights AS
(
    SELECT 
        s.ProductID,
        p.Country,
        p.Product_Type,
        ROUND(p.Latitude, 3) AS Latitude,
        ROUND(p.Longitude, 3) AS Longitude,
        CASE 
            WHEN p.Price > 0 AND p.Price < 500 THEN 1
            WHEN p.Price >= 500  THEN 2 
        END AS PriceGroup,
        COUNT(s.ProductID) AS Weight
    FROM 
        Views s
    JOIN 
        Products p ON s.ProductID = p.ProductID
    WHERE 
        s.ViewDate >= CAST(GETDATE()-7 AS date) 
        AND p.Latitude IS NOT NULL 
        AND p.Longitude IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY 
        s.ProductID, p.Country, p.ProductType,
        CASE WHEN p.Price > 0 AND p.Price < 500 THEN 1
             WHEN p.Price >= 500 THEN 2 END,
        ROUND(p.Latitude, 3),
        ROUND(p.Longitude, 3)
)
```

This CTE gets me the view counts for each product that has been viewed in the last 7 days.

Then I try to get the TOP 3 Products per Country, ProductType, PriceGroup:

```
SELECT TOP 3 WITH TIES
ProductID,
Country,
ProductType,
PriceGroup,
Latitude,
Longitude,
Weight,
DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Latitude,Longitude) As Rank,
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY Country,ProductType ORDER BY Weight DESC) As Rank2
FROM Weights
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Country,ProductType,PriceGroup ORDER BY Weight DESC)
```

#### Issues

1. Only 1 Product is returned for each ProductType and PriceGroup for each Country, rather than 3 for each
2. Rank is not returning an uninterrupted sequence of numbers - i.e. it returns 1,2,4,5,6,8,10,11
3. Rank2 is not returning an uninterrupted sequence from 1 to 3 - i.e. it returns 5,4,1 - I can't actually figure out how it is ranking on any of the columns

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier if you just place `ROW_NUMBER` inside the CTE and then filter it afterwards, rather than using `TOP WITH TIES`.

> Note how I have pre-aggregated `Views` and also applied the calculations inside `APPLY`, this avoids having to repeat any code.

```sql
WITH Weights AS
(
    SELECT 
        p.ProductID,
        p.Country,
        p.Product_Type,
        v.Latitude,
        v.Longitude,
        v.PriceGroup,
        s.Weight,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.Country, p.ProductType, v.PriceGroup
                          ORDER BY s.Weight DESC) AS Rank
    FROM Products p
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS Weight
        FROM Views s
        WHERE s.ViewDate >= CAST(GETDATE()-7 AS date)
          AND s.ProductID = p.ProductID
        GROUP BY s.ProductID
    ) s
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES(
        CASE 
            WHEN p.Price > 0 AND p.Price < 500 THEN 1
            WHEN p.Price >= 500  THEN 2 
        END,
        ROUND(p.Latitude, 3),
        ROUND(p.Longitude, 3)
    )) AS v(PriceGroup, Latitude, Longitude)
    WHERE p.Latitude IS NOT NULL 
      AND p.Longitude IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
  ProductID,
  Country,
  ProductType,
  PriceGroup,
  Latitude,
  Longitude,
  Weight,
  Rank
FROM Weights
WHERE Rank <= 3
ORDER BY
  Rank,
  Country,
  ProductType;
```

Comment: Thank you. There's two missing brackets on CROSS APPLY VALUES but I am also getting an "Invalid column name ProductID" error and I can't see why that would be

Comment: This is almost correct - looking at the returned data, it is outputting Products with no weight/views as well as those that do. I only want to know about products that have been viewed in the last 7 days, and then rank them

Comment: Ok should all be fixed now

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your time and effort. I now just need to add a DENSE_RANK so I can group the Products by the LatLng. I think I can do that.